# Original dlls are affected when running a sub process separately

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, dll, reflection

I am working on a Windows application designed in vb which has quite a number of modules which get attached to it via reflection. The each module also has an embedded sql file attached to it which gets executed when the user logs in.

I was trying to execute these embedded sql file using a separate console. So I extracted the code and built a Console App. The app execution is failing for some modules where I think I might have missed something.
The problem is when I go for the actual app after the console app execution the failed modules also fail in the actual application.

I am not sure why? In a clean setup the original application has no issues.
I am not referencing anything from my console app to the original window application or vice-versa. The application is running on version specific dlls. Can someone help me out in pointing to the right direction ?

Comment: How can we help you? This is not making any sense. No code. No errors. Nothing.

Comment: There are two types of bindings 1) Early Binding : The types are defined when you compile 2) Late Bindings : The types are resolved at run time.  The Late Types do not always work with c#.  You may be dealing with old code that uses ActiveX components which are now considered by Microsoft obsolete (From VB 4, 5 , and 6).

Comment: One of the error i am getting in my execution is 

"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "IDummyInterface", name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[IDummyInterface, null]) failed: The current type, IDummyInterface, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)"

The error is originating from my console app and persisting in the original app.

Comment: @jdweng: Even if this is a late binding scenario how can the error gets passed on to the original execution which was okay at the first place.

Comment: VB does less checking of objects than c#.  c# is managed and to minimize blue screen exceptions c# does check of object to make sure the memory address are within range; and c# validates types when casting.  In your case, c# is detecting an exception and then throwing another exception which is passed to the next level code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your responses, i think it was a Caching/paging issue. Earlier, I tried using some dll files from the original code into my code base but while execution somehow the references were getting messed up where the original dll were getting overridden by the dll my code base had. I took a copy of the original and reapplied them after console execution and everything worked perfectly.